# Track total played time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating game and I need to track some statistics. I want to track **total played time** (since the user started game and till the moment he definitely ended game).

I have a `"continue"` option from main menu, so if someone turned game off and then started it and selected "Continue" - it means that I need to increment the old playedTime because, it is not new player.

How can I track this total played time? I cannot use Editor Scripts because I need this to be available just from the game build (player will start game with `.exe`, not from Unity)

Comment: a public variable and a timer is enough for this calculation

Comment: it wil be reseted on turning the game off. But player can continue on next game starting.

Comment: continue after restart?

Comment: yes. It will load his last scene, last position and all his skills and items.

Comment: do you have database?

Comment: It should be the same as how you retain player's data when you `continue`. Saving it to a file should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the [realtimeSinceStartup](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) on an [ApplicationQuit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html), for example in the playerprefs. Something like this should do the trick:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TimeStatistics : MonoBehaviour
{   
    public float TotalTime
    {
        get
        {
            float totalTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
            if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("totaltime"))
                totalTime += PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("totaltime");
            return totalTime;
        }

    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        PlayerPregs.SetFloat("totaltime", this.TotalTime);
    }
}
```

Make sure the script always exists, otherwise you wont get an OnApplicationQuit!