# Is there a substitute to Processing's millis() in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make a timer in Unity that specifically needs something like millis() from Processing. Is there something that works like it or at least very simmilar?

I tried doing something with Time.time or Time.deltaTime but I couldn't come up with anything.

About millis():
https://processing.org/reference/millis_.html

Comment: Depends what you're doing with it. The [Timer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-6.0) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Look at Time.realtimeSinceStartup.

Comment: What have you already tried? How did its results differ from what you needed? Please share your research.

Comment: @laancelot I didn't know a class like that existed and it'll do just fine. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Track total played time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865953/track-total-played-time)

Comment: @Bart genuine question: do you get the difference between `unscaledTime` and `realtimeSinceStartup` ? They seem to both be kinda the same ...?

Comment: @Ruzihm see comment above ;)

Comment: @derHugo Not sure if this is a practical answer but [the docs for `unscaledTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledTime.html) say "Unlike `Time.realtimeSinceStartup`, this \[(`unscaledTime`)] returns the same value if called multiple times in a single frame and when the Editor is paused."

Comment: @Ruzihm ah yeah that makes sense thanks!

Comment: Yeah @derHugo, Ruzihm is spot on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

<strike>You can use C# System API `System.DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond`
or `System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond` (for your clock's current time)</strike>

Following [Petrusion comment](https://#comment-126483752), You can use `System.Environment.TickCount` which is faster, to get the number of millis since your computer started

If you need the time from the application's start, you can create a monobehaviour wrapper to it

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CustomTimer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int startTime = 0;
    
    void Start()
    {
        startTime = System.Environment.TickCount;
    }
    
    public int MillisSinceStart()
    {
        return System.Environment.TickCount - startTime;
    }
}
```

Then drag it to the scene, get it's reference and call `timer.GetEllapsedTime()` from anywhere

Also unity has both time and frame dependent stuff going on
for example, callback `void Update() { }` is called every frame, unlike `void FixedUpdate() { }` which is called every 0.02 seconds or so (can be changed in settings)

If you're doing animation stuff, maybe it's best to use frame-dependent time instead of regular time, because your app can slow down and cause some frames to be skipped when drawing

Comment: This is wrong. I do not wish to be rude, but this shouldn't be the accepted answer. UtcNow.Millisecond (aside from being very slow for this use case) gives you the milliseconds inside of the currently ongoing second, i.e. it gives you a value between 0 and 999. You should use System.Environment.TickCount instead, that gives you the number of milliseconds since the system/computer started (and is much faster). But even if you use TickCount, this MonoBehaviour is useless because Time.time already gives you the number of seconds (as a float) since the application/game started.

Comment: To your second part .. there already is [`Time.unscaledTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-unscaledTime.html) for that ;) to the first: DateTime is extremely expensive! You certainly would not want to use it frame wise

Comment: @petrusion Oh, you're not being rude at all, I'll try to update the answer with your considerations.
Thank you.